# C++, Duda con random, limitarlot

Tags: c++, random

Mi problema es el siguiente, ocupo establecer 108 números aleatorios, del 1 al 6, pero ocupo que hayan como máximo 3 de cada uno, es decir, 3 unos, 3 dos, y así, no mas, ¿existe alguna forma de limitar el random para obtener eso?

Comment: Bienvenido MuddyThrower, tu pregunta está clara con lo que buscar, pero carece de calidad... Podés ir a [ask] para más información...    Respecto a lo que buscas, si quieres 108  números aleatorios del 1 al 6, y tu condición es que no haya más de 3 de cada uno entonces no podrías generar los 108 que pides... Corrijeme si me equivoco, pero el creo que el cero está demás, no??

Comment: Si es así entonces sería bueno que nos muestres que es lo que tienes hecho hasta ahora, para partir de ahí

Comment: Ok, para especificar mas el caso, necesito 108 fichas para un tablero, cada ficha tiene 6 colores, y hay 6 tipos de fichas, pero no pueden haber mas de 3 fichas iguales, mi idea es hacer un random para crear 108 fichas, generando numeros aleatorios del 1 al 6, sin que hayan mas de 3 fichas/numeros iguales

Comment: Reiterandote, por favor lee en enlace que te di, de paso podes hacer [tour] para saber como funciona el sitio... Edita la pregunta y agrega todo lo que explicas dentro de ella para darle calidad... Por favor lee los enlaces que te envié